# MQTTnet client publishing

Tags: c#

I think my problem is, that I generate the MQTT client new everytime that I call the function. But I don't know how to work around this. I tried connecting the client when the "Publish" Task is called, but then the app just crashes.
If I put a publishing part behind the connecting function, the message gets published.
I just don't know how to manage to not be forced to generate the var MQTTclient new everytime I call the function.
I'm probably overseeing something as I am pretty new to C# and haven't used this library ever.

```
namespace InfiniLight
{
    public class MQTT
    {       

        public static async Task<bool> Publish(string channel, string value)
        {
            var factory = new MqttFactory();
            var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

            if (mqttClient.IsConnected == false)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("publishing failed");
                return false; 
            } 

            var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
                    .WithTopic(channel)
                    .WithPayload(value)
                    .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                    .WithRetainFlag()
                    .Build();
            await mqttClient.PublishAsync(message);
            return true;
        }


        //connect to mqtt

        public static async Task Connect()
        {
            var factory = new MqttFactory();
            var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string mqttURI = Preferences.Get("broker_ip", "");
            string mqttUser = Preferences.Get("client_username", "");
            string mqttPassword = Preferences.Get("client_password", "");
            int i;
            i = System.Convert.ToInt32(Preferences.Get("broker_port", "1883"));
            int mqttPort = i;
            bool mqttSecure = false;
            var messageBuilder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
              .WithClientId(clientId)
              .WithCredentials(mqttUser, mqttPassword)
              .WithTcpServer(mqttURI, mqttPort)
              .WithCleanSession();
            var options = mqttSecure
              ? messageBuilder
                .WithTls()
                .Build()
              : messageBuilder
                .Build();

            Debug.WriteLine("MQTT: connecting");
            await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options, CancellationToken.None);
            Debug.WriteLine("MQTT: connected");

            /*
            var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()                                       
//here it does send the message
                   .WithTopic("hey")
                   .WithPayload("I'm a mobile")
                   .WithExactlyOnceQoS()
                   .WithRetainFlag()
                   .Build();
            await mqttClient.PublishAsync(message); */


        } 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mqttClient` to be a static member of the class rather than a local variable. Then create the connection before you ever call `Publish()`, or create the connection once in `Publish()` and use a condition to check if it's already connected or not. Either way, then you can re-use the same object rather than have to re-create it.

Comment: k, it worked...
when I asked this question, I was pretty new to C#, but forgot to check back to that class... thanks for reminding me ;)